# Is it possible to open a locked android device or access it's files without knowing the password?

Tags: lock-screens, file-system, password, files

I have a Samsung phone which is password protected it also has fingerprint enabled.

I don't need to know how to open it I just want to know if it's possible to unlock it or access its files?

There is someone claiming that he can open it without losing any of the data for a certain amount of money?

Comment: Some Samsung devices have a bug in the MTP protocol that allows to access files on the sdcard section from a PC via USB while the device is locked: https://medium.com/@richarjb/exploit-test-samsung-s6-s7-arbitrary-file-read-write-on-locked-device-via-mtp-626396f7482

Comment: I wouldn't accept this if someone offered me such a service... You can find ways to unlock the system and remove your locks from data...